# grep/regex can't find accented word

Tags: regex, unicode, grep, cat, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying mount a regex that get some words on a file where all letters of this word match with a word pattern.

My problem is, the regex can't find accented words, but in my text file there are alot of accented words.

My command line is:

```
cat input/words.txt | grep '^[éra]\{1,4\}$' > output/words_era.txt
cat input/words.txt | grep '^[carroça]\{1,7\}$' > output/words_carroca.txt
```

And the content of file is:

```
carroça
éra
éssa
roça
roco
rato
onça
orça
roca
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `locale`?  What is the encoding of `input/words.txt`?

Comment: It works for me, but maybe the problem is with your syntax: square brackets are used to define groups of characters, so at least the second line is definitely wrong. Try:

    grep '^carroça\{1,3\}$'

Comment: @UncleZeiv, I had put the regex wrong, now I edited with the correct.

Comment: @ephemient, the locale is: LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
. The encoding of input/words is ISO-8859-1

Comment: ok I see what you want to do, I was just saying that repeating characters in the regex doesn't look right, I would have but `[caroç]` but your works as well.

Comment: It may work but it's still "wrong" in the sense that the regex doesn't really say what you're trying to do. It *looks* like you're trying to match the word `carroça` but it *says* to match any sequence of 1 to 7 of the letters listed. Ziev's shorter `[caroç]` is indeed better. Both will match `carroça` and will also match `roca` and `orça` etc. but will not match `éssa` or `éra`. I point this out only because it seems you *might* not be entirely clear on what the square brackets do in regex.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your file is encoded in ISO-8859-1 but your system locale is UTF-8, this will not work.

Either convert the file to UTF-8 or change your system locale to ISO-8859-1.

```
# convert from ISO-8859-1 to the environmental locale before grepping
# output will be in the current locale
$ iconv -f 8859_1 input/words.txt | grep ...

# run grep with an ISO-8859-1 locale
# output will be in ISO-8859-1 encoding
$ cat input/words.txt | env LC_ALL=en_US grep ...
```

Comment: Dude, the first option "iconv" works. Thanks. The output now is carroça
roça
roco
orça
roca
car
raa

Answer (score 2):

I found a related question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/218825/using-find-or-grep-to-locate-filenames-with-accented-characters-from-a-different) that seems to work.

So if you try something like:

```
cat input/words.txt | LANG=C grep '^[éra]\{1,4\}$' > output/words_era.txt
```

Does that produce what you expect?

Comment: unfortunately no, the output is the same.

Comment: forgot to escape the \, so they weren't showing up in the post

Comment: in these cases just add some space at the front and the line will format as code, which is more readable and doesn't need escapes. I've done this for you here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything is UTF-8, I’d usually just use something like

```
perl -CSAD -le 'print if /^carroça{1,3}$/' filenames
```

because then I know what it’s doing.

Comment: The comments (eventually) make it clear that not everything is UTF-8, though.

Comment: @ephemient Encoding tribulations seem to be endless, don’t they?

Answer (score 0):

Try as @dule said, but with `LANG=en_US.iso88591`:

```
cat input/words.txt | LANG=en_US.iso88591 grep '^[éra]\{1,4\}$' > output/words_era.txt
```

Comment: @ephemient: I found it using `locale -a` and this was tested on my machine and it works, after reproducing the same situation as GodFather's.

Comment: Depends on how the system was set up (possibly influenced by `/etc/locale.gen`) but having named ISO-8859-1 locales is not common in Linux distributions anymore.

Comment: @ephemient: I see; indeed, I'm working on a very old Linux distribution