# can grep identify only one matching word in a file?

Tags: grep, cpu-word, diacritics

I have a file with a list of word and I want to identify only the word in the file which exactly matches another word?

So, for example, if I have in the file, the words "BEBE, BEBÉ, BEBÉS", and I look for "BEBE", I want it to return just the first one, which is the exact match.

I tried using grep -w "BEBE" filename.txt, but it doesn't work. It still gives me back all three of them.

Comment: Is the problem that it's matching all three on the line?  Or that it is returning multiple matching lines in the same file?

Comment: show us exactly what the input file looks like, and exactly what you're expecting as output, and this should be trivial to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-o` to only display the part that matches with `-w`, also use `-F` for fixed string if you're not `regex` matching:

```
$ cat file
BEBE, BEBÉ, BEBÉS

$ grep -woF 'BEBÉ' file
BEBÉ

$ grep -woF 'BEBÉS' file
BEBÉS
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. It retunrs "BEBE BEBE BEBE" and I also need the rest of the line after the matching word, and in this case, the line is deleted.

Comment: What does `locale` and `file file` produce `file: UTF-8 Unicode text`? This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739480/grep-regex-cant-find-accented-word) might be of use